# Strict Inequality in Rudin's Proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

In Rudin's proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem (step ten), he proves that

$$\Lambda h_i \leq \mu(V_i) < \mu(E_i) + \epsilon/n , \quad \mu(K) \leq \sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} \Lambda h_i.$$

Writing $A = \sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} \Lambda h_i$, he then asserts that

$$\sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} (|a|+y_i+\epsilon)\Lambda h_i - |a| A  \leq \sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} (|a|+y_i+\epsilon)(\mu(E_i) + \epsilon/n) - |a|\mu(K).$$

My question is, how does he avoid strict inequality? As $\Lambda h_i  < \mu(E_i) + \epsilon/n$, it seems to follow that

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} (|a|+y_i+\epsilon)\Lambda h_i - |a| A  &< \sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} (|a|+y_i+\epsilon)(\mu(E_i) + \epsilon/n) - |a|A\\
&\leq \sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} (|a|+y_i+\epsilon)(\mu(E_i) + \epsilon/n) - |a|\mu(K)
\end{align*}
$$
and therefore that

$$\sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} (|a|+y_i+\epsilon)\Lambda h_i - |a| A  < \sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} (|a|+y_i+\epsilon)(\mu(E_i) + \epsilon/n) - |a|A.$$

Comment: Well, even if. When the strict inequality holds, the weak one holds too. Since at the end one does a limiting operation $\varepsilon \to 0$, the end result would be a (the desired) weak inequality, whether he wrote a strict or weak one before. (Yes, the strict inequality does hold there, but one can always write something weaker than actually holds if convenient.)

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure if this was merely for convenience or not; its my first time studying analysis and I want to make sure I don't miss any subtleties.

Comment: Oh, you're doing **fine** _detecting_ subtleties, it seems. Very promising.

Comment: @DanielFischer Maybe your first comment could be an answer.

Comment: I'm studying this proof and have two very naive questions. 1. Why can we claim that $\Lambda h_i\leq \mu(V_i)$? 2. Do we need to have $y_i\geq 0$, in order to use this in the inequality below?

Answer (score 1):

Answered in a comment:

> Well, even if. When the strict inequality holds, the weak one holds too. Since at the end one does a limiting operation $\varepsilon \to 0$, the end result would be a (the desired) weak inequality, whether he wrote a strict or weak one before. (Yes, the strict inequality does hold there, but one can always write something weaker than actually holds if convenient.)  --[Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) [Jun 29 '13 at 20:56](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432587/strict-inequality-in-rudins-proof-of-the-riesz-representation-theorem#comment925166_432587)